# JavaScript - Add class for all disabled <A> tags in an unordered list

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a style class to any hyperlinks within an unordered list that are not disabled.  Can someone help me? I've got this code running onload

```
function ApplyCSSToDisableElements() {

        var a = document.getElementById('Pager').getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

                if (a.disabled == true) 
                {
                    alert("disabled");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Not disabled");
                }
        }
    }
```

And here is the list:

```
<ul id="Pager" class="center">                            
<li><a disabled="disabled">1</a></li>
<li><a >2</a></li>
<li><a disabled="disabled">3</a></li>
<li><a disabled="disabled">4</a></li>
<li><a >5</a></li>
<li><a disabled="disabled">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, I keep receiving the same alert.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies the list code has gone bizarre:  <ul id="Pager" class="center">                            
<li><a disabled="disabled">1</a></li>
<li><a >2</a></li>
<li><a disabled="disabled">3</a></li>
<li><a disabled="disabled">4</a></li>
<li><a >5</a></li>
<li><a disabled="disabled">6</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code, although you are not using right approach but still if you want, you can use below code -

JS fiddle link - 
https://jsfiddle.net/38c9tj4e/

```
 function ApplyCSSToDisableElements() {

    var a = document.getElementById('Pager').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (a[i].getAttribute('disabled')=="disabled") 
            {
                alert("disabled");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Not disabled");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the wrong variable - you should be looking at `a[i]`, not `a`.

Beyond that, the `.disabled` property doesn't exist on `<a>` elements - you've added a non-standard attribute, so you'd need to test for the existence of that, either by looping and using `a[i].getAttribute()`, or better still using `parent.querySelectorAll('a:[disabled="disabled"]')` instead of `getElementsByTagName()` to get the list of elements pre-filtered.

Either way, the real solution is to do this within your style sheet without any code at all:

```
#Pager a:[disabled="disabled"] {
    ...
}
```

This will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll to select the disabled elements and then just iterate over that list.

```js
function ApplyCSSToDisableElements (){
  var a = document.querySelectorAll("#Pager a[disabled='disabled']");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].classList.add('disabled')
  }
}

ApplyCSSToDisableElements();
```

```css
.disabled
{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="Pager" class="center">
  <li><a disabled="disabled">1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a disabled="disabled">3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a disabled="disabled">4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>5</a>
  </li>
  <li><a disabled="disabled">6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: modifying `.className` like that isn't safe

Comment: `element.classList.add('disabled')`

Comment: @Alnitak Okk,  yeah people may miss the space in front of the new class while  adding. Good Point.